# reload bookmarks file without restarting Emacs?

Tags: bookmarks

I'm using Emacs (latest master branch as of June,2017) and I'm using Syncthing (like Dropbox) to store my emacs-bookmark file which I load in my configuration using

```
'(bookmark-default-file "~/Sync/emacs-bookmarks")
```

On one computer I have to do a `bookmark-save` command to output my current bookmarks to the `~/Sync/emacs-bookmarks` file. On the other computer this file is updated but when I do a list of bookmarks using `C-x r l` the listing is not refreshed it's showing the old bookmarks.

Is there a way without restarting emacs to reload the bookmarks file?

Comment: There are two popular threads that deal with synchronizing packages and user-configurations across multiple computers, including, but not limited to using DropBox.  It may behoove you to consider editing your question title, and perhaps the body of the question to distinguish your question.  At first glance, I immediately assumed it was a duplicate. Then, I read it a couple of times and saw it was about bookmarks, but I didn't quite get the gist of the question.  Perhaps another forum participant will immediately understand this question as being different and will have an answer . . ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call `bookmark-load`. You don't need Bookmark+.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bookmark+. There are a lot of things in that package but this is very handy:

```
bookmark-load is an interactive compiled Lisp function in  bookmark+-1.el .

It is bound to C-x p l, <menu-bar> <edit> <bookmark> <load>.

(bookmark-load FILE &optional OVERWRITE BATCHP)

Load bookmarks from FILE (which must be in the standard format).
Without a prefix argument (argument OVERWRITE is nil), add the newly
loaded bookmarks to those already current.  They are saved to the
current bookmark file when bookmarks are saved.
```

I also set this in my init file:

```
(setq bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file nil) ;; always uses the value of  bookmark-default-file  as the initial bookmark file
```

Comment: I don't think you need `bookmark+` to reload the bookmarks file.  `bookmark-load` is part of `bookmark.el`.

Comment: What @Dan says is true. `bookmark-load` exists also in vanilla Emacs (i.e., without [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus)). But interactively it does not switch to a different bookmark file. See the doc string in Bookmark+ for the differences in behavior. Or see the comment before the Bookmark+ definition. In particular, with the Bookmark+ version, a prefix arg *switches* to using the bookmark file you specify (instead of just *adding* its bookmarks). In the bookmark-list display (`C-x r l`) you can use **`L`** to switch to another bookmark file.